# Why does Cypress.io use string assertion type selectors, what are alternatives?

Tags: cypress

I need a e2e test tool, among those I tried I think Cypress.io seems to be the best.

What I don't understand is why they use string selectors in should() clause like this (I need our testers to have easy time as possible, and I don't think error-prone strings are the way to go):

```
cy.get('.trigger-input-range')
  .invoke('val', 25)
  .trigger('change')
  .get('input[type=range]').siblings('p')
  .should('have.text', '25')
```

I've been able to sucessfuly use something like this:

```
cy.get('.trigger-input-range')
  .invoke('val', 25)
  .trigger('change')
  .get('input[type=range]').siblings('p')
  .should((e) => {
    expect(e).to.have.text('25')
  });
```

this at least gives me some safety with IDE offering some options like "have.text", "have.value" (I plan to use Typescript for these tests, so any suggestions that may help are welcome. Does this have some side-effect? If no, I don't understand them using those string selectors.

Is there any other option?
Could I somehow modify Cypress to have something like this?

```
cy.get('.trigger-input-range')
  .invoke('val', 25)
  .trigger('change')
  .get('input[type=range]').siblings('p')
  .shouldHaveText('25')
  .shouldHaveValue('25');
```

Comment: This is an interesting question, I often wondered the same thing myself. but I still prefer cypress..

Answer (score 4):

```js
.should('have.text', '25');
```

is analogous to this:

```js
.should(elem => {
    expect(elem).to.have.text('25');
});
```

They are simply two ways of doing the same thing. The shorter one is an inline way to use the [Chai assertion](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Chai) from the longer one, but it will produce the same result.

If you want a command like `.shouldHaveText('25')`, you should be able to get it by creating your own [custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Child-Commands):

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('shouldHaveText', {
  prevSubject: true
}, (subject, expectedText) => {
    // Wrap the subject and use .should() to take advantage of automatic retries
    cy.wrap(subject).should((elem) => {
        expect(elem).to.have.text(expectedText);
    });
});
```

Usage:

```js
cy.get('.someClass').shouldHaveText('25');
```

Comment: Interesting. Will your new command have intellisense? Perhaps adding typescipt will help. I for one just remember all the magic strings.. but I will consider your answer..

Comment: I have no idea. I suspect that something like VS Code would need an extra plugin for that.